# YouTube webhook subscribe request returning "Invalid value for hub.mode"?

Tags: javascript, youtube-data-api, webhooks

I'm trying to subscribe to a webhook (post notifications) on YouTube and I keep getting the error `Invalid value for hub.mode` even though I ensured it was "subscribe."

Here is my post body:

```
{
  "hub.callback": "http://x.x.x.x:xxxx/xxxxxxx",
  "hub.topic": "https://www.youtube.com/xml/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=x",
  "hub.verify": "async",
  "hub.mode": "subscribe",
  "hub.verify_token": verifyToken,
  "hub.secret": secret,
  "hub.lease_seconds": 864000
}
```

I've tried it capitalized too, didn't work. Any ideas? The post is short and I don't give a lot of information, but there is no other information I can give that would help you, but if you know why this happens could you let me know?

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue. Making the request with Postman doesn't have any problems but doing it in nodejs does. Have you found a fix?

Comment: No, I haven't found a fix for it.

Comment: You can put it in the url actually. i.e. `/subscribe?hub.callback=whatever...&hub.mode=subscribe` and that seems to work

Comment: I'll try it out, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Intoxicated Penguin for the suggestion to put the post data in with the url as a query itself, that seemed to have worked.

So my path changed from `/subscribe` to `/subscribe?hub.callback=xxx...&hub.mode=subscribe` and it worked since then!

Answer (score 2):

The other thing I found caused this error, is if the content type was **not** set to multipart/form-data